# Git How to move work from one local folder to another without pushing upstream to origin

Tags: git

I have two working folders pointing to the same origin

In ~/working-1, I am at branch-1 (only exists in this folder)

In ~/working-2, I am at branch-2 (only exists in this folder)

Now I want to move my work at branch-1 in ~/working-1 to ~/working-2

So the result will be in ~/working-2, I will be at branch-1

I can accomplish this by pushing to origin first.  But if there a way to do it without pushing to origin?

Comment: You can use a local git repo as a *remote* for another local repo, and push/fetch between them. Alternatively, this is a use case for [git worktrees](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree).

Comment: ... or you can create patches and apply them on the other repo. But using remotes is fairly simple.

Comment: Check this out. It should help - https://medium.com/@ayushya/move-directory-from-one-repository-to-another-preserving-git-history-d210fa049d4b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cd ~/working-1
git push ~/working-2 branch-1
```

pushes the new history and sets the ref

```
cd ~/working-2
git checkout branch-1
```

checks it out.

remote names are easy shorthand for paths or urls, and a lot of other things it can be helpful to remember about repos you talk to a lot, but they're not necessary, you can just give them directly.

Another way to get it done with less cd'ing is

```
cd ~/working-2
git fetch ~/working-1 branch-1
git checkout -b branch-1 FETCH_HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

Make ~/working-1 a remote of ~/working-2.

```
cd ~/working-2
git remote add working-1 ~/working-1
```

Fetch its changes. This is safe and will not alter any local branches.

```
git fetch working-1
```

And checkout its branch-1 as your local branch-1.

```
git checkout -b branch-1 working-1/branch-1
```